# Difficulty setting a legend with statsmodels Python package

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, statsmodels

I'm currently using the statsmodels Python package in order to plot an autocorrelation graph for two assets that I have (it's for a finance assignment as part of my masters), but I'm having issues with setting a legend so that the markers correspond to the actual assets. For instance, the blue marker corresponds to 'Asset A', whereas the green marker corresponds to 'Asset B'. However, an additional two lines keep appearing in the legend, and I somehow can't get rid of them! All I want to do is have a legend with two markers that correspond to each asset, but dealing with plots for this package has been an absolute nightmare so far, and has been considerably harder than dealing with matplotlib or anything I've stumbled upon ever before! My current code is as follows:

```
acf_assetA=sm.tsa.stattools.acf(returns_assetA,nlags=40)
acf_assetB=sm.tsa.stattools.acf(returns_assetB,nlags=40)
legendA='Asset A'
legendB='Asset B'
legendC='Asset C'
legendD='Asset B'
autocorr_plot1,ax1=plt.subplots(figsize=(6,5))
ax1.set_xlabel('Lag')
autocorr_plot1=sm.tsa.graphics.plot_acf(returns_assetA,ax=ax1,lags=np.arange(40),label='Asset A')
autocorr_plot2=sm.tsa.graphics.plot_acf(returns_assetB,ax=ax1,lags=np.arange(40),label='Asset B')
ax1.legend([legendA,legendB,legendC,legendD],loc='best',shadow=True)

return autocorr_plot1, autocorr_plot2, acf_assetA, acf_assetB
```

It's quite useful to know that

```
returns_assetA, returns_assetB
```

are simply the returns for my assets contained within a Pandas dataframe.

And this is how the plot that I keep obtaining looks like (ignore the 'Asset C' part of the legend - I just simply put that because I keep being forced to include four inputs for my legend in order for the green markers to show up):

[image]

Any kind of help with going about this legend issue would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plot_acf` function creates 3 objects on the canvas:
**[ZL]** a line at zero,
**[P]**  the points of the correlation,
**[VL]** the vertical lines connecting the points to zero.

The way they appear in the legend is
[ZL1] [P1] [ZL2] [P2] ..  [ZLn] [Pn] [VL1] [VL2] .. [VLn]

[image]

The idea would therefore be to select out of those only the desired handles. Therefore we'd first get all the handles and labels

```
handles, labels= ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
```

and then first drop the last `len(handles)//3` items (the vertical lines).

```
handles=handles[:-len(handles)//3]
```

The we'd only select every other item starting at 1.

```
handles=handles[1::2]
```

This is then how the complete solution could look like:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools, statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

autocorr_plot1,ax1=plt.subplots(figsize=(6,5))
ax1.set_xlabel('Lag')

autocorr_plot1=statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf(np.random.rand(16),ax=ax1, label='Asset A')
autocorr_plot2=statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf(np.random.rand(16),ax=ax1, label='Asset B')
#uncomment for testing purposes
#autocorr_plot3=statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf(np.random.rand(16),ax=ax1, label='Asset C')
#autocorr_plot4=statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf(np.random.rand(16),ax=ax1, label='Asset D')

handles, labels= ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles=handles[:-len(handles)//3][1::2]
labels =labels[:-len(handles)//3][1::2]
ax1.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels,loc='best',shadow=True, numpoints=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally worked! I just wish that the statsmodels developers would make the plotting aspect of the package a bit more user-friendly.

Comment: You may open a bug report or feature request at the [statsmodel developement page](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues).

Comment: Thanks, I will do so :)